# How to implement autofill in a form which is opened in chromium embedded framework?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, autofill, chromium-embedded

I have an html form when run on chrome is implementing autocomplete feature by clicking in the input fields of the form and giving the options to select the data and populating other fields.
But when running in chromium embedded framework, it is not autocompleting. Even on clicking the input fields it is not showing the data as was shown in chrome.
Please help!
Is autofill feature implemented in chromium embedded framework?

Comment: *Is autofill feature implemented in chromium embedded framework?* Yes, it is.

Comment: *How to implement autofill in a form which is opened in chromium embedded framework?* Create the browser with proper settings, particularly `cache_path`.